# Risk factors and diversification in asset pricing models

Tags: finance, asset-pricing

Consider a factor model like [Fama and French (1993)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fama%E2%80%93French_three-factor_model). Total risk has two components, systematic risk and idiosyncratic risk. Idiosyncratic risk can be [diversified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversification_(finance)) while systematic risk cannot. Systematic risk is the risk that amounts to the priced risk factors of the model.

My question is: **when can the risk of a factor be diversified?**
Can there be a priced and a diversifiable risk factor? Does this implies that investors hold not diversified portfolios?